# How to get list of shared folders in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, file-sharing

I need to detect in my MacOS app, that dropped file on a canvas belongs to shared folder.

The only way which I have found was calling a command inside terminal:

```
sharing -l
```

so I have called such command in swift and parsed output.

This solution works but I have noticed that it works only when you have Admin rights.

Is there any solution to gather list of shared folders also when user has Standard account (without admin rights)?

It would be great if some framework method exists (calling terminal command is not my preferred way).